# datagrid editcommand set dropdownlist selectedvalue

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, drop-down-menu

I have a datagrid and I want to set the value of a dropdownlist in editcommand.

However, I can't find the control?

Here's my .net:

```
Private Sub dgUsers_EditCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles dgUsers.EditCommand

    Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.Cells(3).FindControl("ddlRole"), DropDownList)
    'ddl.SelectedValue = "20"

    dgUsers.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex
    Call bindUsers()
    dgUsers.ShowFooter = False
End Sub
```

Here's my html:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Role">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GetRoleName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList id="ddlRole" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="User" Value="0" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="WRA" Value="10" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin" Value="20" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

While debugging in the EditCommand, I can find the Label (lblRole), but not the dropdownlist.

Thoughts?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. Even though the IDE doesn't show the property, you can set the SelectedValue on the design side:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList id="ddlRole" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("GetRoleId") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="User" Value="0" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="WRA" Value="10" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin" Value="20" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
```